# Android: Using Gradle for build .apk with time stamp used in About page of the app

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to use Gradle for creating apk with time stamp in file name and also utilise this information on about page.

Gradle:
(below) works fine in creating output file as DSapp-1.2.0-debug_date_time.apk

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def project = "DSapp"
        def sep = "_"
        def version = variant.versionName
        def newApkName = project + sep + version + sep + formattedDateD + "_" + formattedDateT + ".apk"

        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
    }
}
```

when I try to use `buildConfigField` like

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

def date = new Date();
def formattedDateD = date.format('ddMMyy');
def formattedDateT = date.format('HHmm');

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app_name"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.2.0"



    buildConfigField "String", "STRING2", formattedDateD
    buildConfigField "String", "STRING3", formattedDateT

}
```

About.java:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    version_number = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.version_number);
    version_number.setText(mVersionName);

    mVersionBuild= "( " + BuildConfig.STRING2 +"_"+BuildConfig.STRING3+ " )";
    version_build = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.version_build);
    version_build.setText(mVersionBuild);
```

I am getting error in `BuildConfig.java`

```
  // Fields from default config.
  public static final String STRING2 = 281116;
  public static final String STRING3 = 0947;
```

`Error:(15, 40) error: integer number too large: 0947`

Comment: Java basics string variables should have apostrophes => check documentation how to use `buildConfigField` with strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to achieve using Gradle for creating apk with time stamp in file name and also utilise this information on about page.
I had to change my approach and abandon idea of using `buildConfigField` as not required to achieve above.

Gradle file:

to every `versionNameSuffix` add  `'_' + getDateTime()`

and

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            customAPKname(variant, defaultConfig, versionNameSuffix)
        }
```

so every section of `buildType` will look like this(example for debug):

```
debug {
        versionNameSuffix '-debug' + '_' + getDateTime()

        //to handle customAPKname build
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        customAPKname(variant, defaultConfig, versionNameSuffix)
        }
}
```

outside of `android{}` add:

```
//to handle build process with output as: App_Name_versionName-buildType_date_time.apk
def customAPKname(variant, defaultConfig, buildType) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->    
        def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
        def fileName = "App_Name" + defaultConfig.versionName + buildType + ".apk"
            output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }
}

def getDateTime(){
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyMMdd_HHmm')
    return formattedDate
}
```

Now in About.java file:

```
private TextView version_number, version_build;
private String mVersionName, mVersionBuild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    if (BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.contains("debug")){
        mVersionName = "App_Name Software version: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.substring(0,11);
        mVersionBuild = "Build version: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.substring(12);
    }else {
        mVersionName = "App_Name Software version: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.substring(0, 13);
        mVersionBuild = "Build version: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.substring(14);
    }

    version_number = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.version_number);
    version_number.setText(mVersionName);

    version_build = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.version_build);
    version_build.setText(mVersionBuild);

}
```

output(for debug): `App_Name_1.2.0-debug_YYMMDD_HHMM.apk`